# Descenders in floats

Tags: floats, typography, double-sided

In a two-sided document it is important to vertically align the left and right pages. When I use a bottom-aligned float, it does not align perfectly (there is a mismatch between how [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) are handled) - see an example below.

Is there a way to unify this? Ideally, modifying the way floats are handled?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,twoside,final]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[papersize={160mm, 210mm}, showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-4]    
    \begin{figure}[b!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
        \caption{\lipsum[1] Qqg}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Technically, the descenders don't reach the bottom of the float.  \caption adds the extra space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

You  can back up over the depth of the last line.

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,twoside,final]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[papersize={160mm, 210mm}, showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-4]    
    \begin{figure}[b!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}
        \caption{\lipsum[1] Qqg}
\vspace{-\prevdepth}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted! Is there a reason, why this is not the default behavior?

Comment: @Ondrian it's tricky to get right but it could do better, but in general the float may go top and then if the last box is not just text, say a tabular that by default is vertically centred you might vspace up several lines and over print the following text